# Package Installation Error In Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: installation, reference, components, nuget-package, mysql.data

Please I was busy for the past 4 days trying to fix the issues resulting from the below error. Please how do I go about fixing this error below?
*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error:      Failed to add reference to 'comerr64'.
Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
*

So I tried reinstalling the Microsoft visual studio 2019 to see if things would go well but all trials were to avail. Then I've also tried several times to reinstall the Nuget package "**MySql.Data** (8.0.32) by oracle, 54.1M downloads" after all trials to fix this but all I got was same error.

Answer (score -1):

There is bug with MySqlData 8.0.32.  The workaround is installing MySqlConnector.  This link explains it:

https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/failed-add-reference-comerr/

The error message went away once it was installed and the site is working.

I left MySqlData in the manifest (installed) for now because there are some dependencies to the other MySQL assemblies that require MySqlData installed that will make if difficult to remove at this point.

Comment: How is using a completely different library a fix?